# Web API Service - How to use "HttpContext.Current" inside async task

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await, httpcontext

I'm using a "Post" async method of webApi rest service:

```
public async Task<object> Post([FromBody]string data)
{
      object response = ExecuteServerLogics(data);

      return response;
}
```

This above code worked good but in some of the client's calls, we experienced performance issues.

After reading some articles here, i've noticed that our webApi rest service,
is not really working asynchronously with its incoming web requests,
because we forgot to use **async/await pattern** :

```
public async Task<object> Post([FromBody]string data)
{
      object response = await Task<object>.Run( () =>
      {
           return ExecuteServerLogics(data);
      });

      return response;
}
```

After this fix we noticed the performance got better,
but we found another critic problem: 
when accessing **HttpContext.Current** - it returns Null reference:

```
public async Task<object> Post([FromBody]string data)
{
      object response = await Task<object>.Run( () =>
      {
           var currentContext = HttpContext.Current; // Returns Null!
           return ExecuteServerLogics(data);
      });

      return response;
}
```

We tried to found a solution for it, and in most posts we found that we should pass the
worker thread's **HttpContext** reference into the inner Task that executes the server logics.
The problem with this solution is that the server's logics methods, use many static classes that use
**"HttpContext.Current"** such as -

1. Loggers calls.
2. static security classes that retrieves the user.identity
3. static security classes that retrives the incoming request's session data, etc.

Therefore, passing the **"HttpContext.Current"** reference of the worker thread won't solve it.

When we tried the next solution:

```
public async Task<object> Post([FromBody]string data)
    {
          // Save worker context:
          var currentContext = HttpContext.Current; 

          object response = await Task<object>.Run( () =>
          {
               // Set the context of the current task :
               HttpContext.Current = currentContext ; // Causes the calls not to work asynchronously for some reason!

               // Executes logics for current request:
               return ExecuteServerLogics(data);
          });

          return response;
    }
```

for some reason, we noticed the performance got worse again, like it had returned working synchronously again.

***Our problems are:***

**1.** Why in the last example, setting the **"HttpContext.Current"** inside the await task,
causes the requests to return the same bad performance results which similar to the **synchronous** results?

**2.** Is there another way we can use **"HttpContext.Current"** inside the inner task that call - "ExecuteServerLogics",
and in all the static classes which also call **"HttpContext.Current"**?
am I doing the entire design wrong somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the beginning:

```
public async Task<object> Post([FromBody]string data)
{
  object response = ExecuteServerLogics(data);
  return response;
}
```

Don't ignore compiler warnings; the compiler will generate a warning for this method that specifically states it will run synchronously.

Moving on:

> in some of the client's calls, we experienced performance issues.

Asynchronous code on the server will *not* be faster for a single call in isolation. It only helps you *scale* your server.

In particular, `Task.Run` will negate all the performance benefits of `async` and then degrade performance a bit beyond that. I believe the improvement in performance that you measured was coincidental.

> in most posts we found that we should pass the worker thread's HttpContext reference into the inner Task that executes the server logics.

Those posts are wrong. IMHO. You end up using the `HttpContext` object from a background thread, when that object is specifically designed to be only accessed from a request thread.

> am I doing the entire design wrong somehow?

I do recommend you take a step back and think about the big picture. When a request comes in, it has a certain amount of work to do. Whether that work is done synchronously or asynchronously is immaterial to the client; both approaches will take about the same amount of time.

If you need to return *early* to the client, then you'll need a completely different architecture. The usual approach is to queue the work to a reliable queue (e.g., Azure queue), have a separate backend (e.g., Azure WebRole), and proactively notify the client when the work is completed (e.g., SignalR).

That's not to say that `async` is useless, though. If `ExecuteServerLogics` is an I/O bound method, then it should be made asynchronous rather than blocking, and then you can use asynchronous methods as such:

```
public async Task<object> Post([FromBody]string data)
{
  object response = await ExecuteServerLogicsAsync(data);
  return response;
}
```

This will enable your server to be more responsive and scalable overall (i.e., not get overwhelmed by many requests).

Comment: Thanks a lot. The main reason we called our method inside task.run, is that our logic's main work - is querying data from the DB (we're using ODP.net without entity framework). The problem was that "await" must be applied to a method call that returns Task<object>, but we don't have Tasks returned in our logics, we mainly using ODP commands and wrap our data in common object which will be serialized to JSON. Therefore, we couldn't return Task<object> from our logics method and called it inside Task.Run. Hםw can we implement your suggestion using - "await ExecuteServerLogicsAsync(data);"  ?

Comment: You'll have to wait for ODP to support `async` or use EF6.

Comment: There is still something vague in this manner for me, if i understood correctly - there is no alternative for my logics method to support the use of async\await? like wrapping the logics code somehow inside some custom task which wrap my logics ? I can only use await with framework classes that were designated to return Task object to use in await call like in EF6?

Comment: That is correct. You cannot make something truly asynchronous if it only exposes a blocking API. If you're writing a UI app, you can pretend it is asynchronous by wrapping it in a `Task.Run`; this burns a thread pool thread. `Task.Run` is detrimental to ASP.NET apps for this reason.

Comment: 1. In this case, till i use ODP async somehow, or use EF6, i have no alternative but to remove the Task.Run use and to use the WebApi Post method without async/await pattern?

2. If i can't use async in some why here, what would you recommend to do in order to  improve the performance
for each web request call in the rest service logics?

Comment: 1. Correct. 2. There's no easy answer. You can try things like parallel processing, but since your underlying methods are blocking, that will kill your scalability in exchange for faster per-request processing.

Comment: I'll try it. About the "HttpContext.Current" issue - I still can't figure out some point - 
Even if i will use Async in EF6 for instance, how will i be able to use my static classes that use 'HttpContext.Current' (logger for instance)
when logging calls and errors from DB operations which will be executed asynchronously? Since "Await" must applies to a method that returns task, doesn't it mean that i'll still lose the 'HttpContext.Current' inside the returned task scope?

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` flows appropriately when you use `async` and `await`. It does not flow if you explicitly use a background thread, e.g., `Task.Run`.

Comment: Got it! Thanks again:) By the way,
in your response, you mentioned that "If you need to return early to the client, then you'll need a completely different architecture" - 
1. Why this requirement can't be achieved in WebApi service? Isn't there something to configure or implementing in our controller that can manage this purpose and to improve the web request's handling performance?

2. If we can't implement this need in WebApi, which different architecture would you recommend us to use instead of WebApi?
3. Is WCF preferred at the performance level?

Comment: 1. ASP.NET wasn't designed to do extra work beyond serving HTTP requests. 2. I outline the architecture in my answer; WebAPI is a *part* of the solution. 3. WCF won't solve any performance problems you have.

Comment: What is considered to be the "extra work" in my case? Because our logics is actually main DB and XML operations designed to serve HTTP request and not beyond that.

Comment: What I mean by "extra work beyond serving HTTP requests" is "doing anything after the response is sent".

Comment: Where is it related in my example? after the server logics is executed the response is returned to the client and i don't need to do some extra work, did i miss something?

Comment: That's **if** you choose the "return early" architecture.

Comment: It helps a lot, tnx. About the asynchronous handling - Are The web requests at the WebApi server handled asynchronously? without considering the async/await pattern but only the WebApi architecture - Can we be sure that all the requests are handled asynchronously and in parallel where each web request executed in separated worker thread at the WebApi server?

Comment: This is no longer really part of the original question.

Comment: @StephenCleary I know this is some thread necromancy but thank you for the comment about the context not restoring when you manually do a Task.Run...this was killing me in WebAPI :D

Comment: really detailed answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If your task is inside your ApiController-derived class, you can use:

```
var ctx = this.Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] as System.Web.HttpContextWrapper;
```

This will give you an HttpContext wrapper with all the usual properties.

Answer (score 0):

Amir I think you're looking for something like this below.  I've been dealing with the same issue, trying to optimize a series of calls.  It needs to be async all the way through, which means your ExecuteServerLogics() would need to be async, and you'd have to mark the containing lamda as async as well.

I believe following that pattern you can probably eliminate most of your performance issues.  Nice passing the context through like that.

```
public async Task<object> Post([FromBody]string data)
{
      // Save worker context:
      var currentContext = HttpContext.Current; 

      object response = await Task<object>.Run(async () =>
      {
           // Set the context of the current task :
           HttpContext.Current = currentContext ;

           // Executes logics for current request:
           return await ExecuteServerLogics(data);
      });

      return response;
}
```