# Parallelizing synchronous tasks while retaining the HttpContext.Current in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, task

I've scoured the SO for answers but found none that pertain to the problem at hand, although [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39707079/79444) nails it on "why", but isn't solving it.

I have a REST endpoint that needs to gather data from other endpoints - in doing so, it accesses the `HttpContext` (setting authentication, headers, etc... all done with 3rd party lib I don't have access to).

Unfortunately, this library for service communication is made to be synchronous, and we want to parallelize its use.

In the following example (abstracted) code, the issue is that `CallEndpointSynchronously` unfortunately uses some built in authentication, which throws null exception when `HttpContext` isn't set:

```
public class MyController: ApiController
//...

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoIt(IEnumerable<int> inputs)
{
    var tasks = inputs.Select(i => 
              Task.Run(()=> 
                 {
                    /* call some REST endpoints, pass some arguments, get the response from each.
                    The obvious answer (HttpContext.Current = parentContext) can't work because 
                    there's some async code underneath (for whatever reasons), and that would cause it 
                    to sometimes not return to the same thread, and basically abandon the Context, 
                    again resulting in null */

                    var results = Some3rdPartyTool.CallEndpointSynchronously(MyRestEndpointConfig[i]);
                    return results;
                 });
    var outcome = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    // collect outcome, do something with it, render outputs... 
}
```

Is there a cure for this?
We want to optimize for single requests, not interested in maximizing parallel users at this moment.

Comment: If I understood Stephen Cleary in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23791651/79444), it basically cannot be done... right?

Comment: What framework is it? .NET 4, 4.5?

Comment: Well if it is 4.5 or above, you could try using this - https://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2013/09/aspnet-web-api-httpcontextcurrent-is.html
Not sure if it will work for this specific case though

Comment: @NikitaChayka: it's 4.7.2

Comment: So try what i provided, might help, though again - not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately, this library for service communication is made to be synchronous, and we want to parallelize its use.

> throws null exception when HttpContext isn't set:

> The obvious answer (HttpContext.Current = parentContext) can't work because                     there's some async code underneath (for whatever reasons), and that would cause it                     to sometimes not return to the same thread, and basically abandon the Context,                     again resulting in null

There's an important part of your question in the example code comment. :)

Normally, `HttpContext` shouldn't be shared across threads. It's just not threadsafe at all. But you *can* set `HttpContext.Current` (for some reason), so you can choose to live dangerously.

The more insidious problem here is that the library has a synchronous API *and* is doing sync-over-async - but somehow without deadlocking (?). At this point, I must be honest and say the best approach is to fix the library: make the vendor fix it, or submit a PR, or just rewrite it if you have to.

However, there is a tiny chance that you can get this kinda sorta working by adding Even More Dangerous code.

So, here's the information you need to know:

- ASP.NET (pre-Core) uses an `AspNetSynchronizationContext`. This context:

  - Ensures that only one thread runs in this context at a time.
  - Sets `HttpContext.Current` for any thread that is running in the context.

Now, you *could* capture the `SynchronizationContext.Current` and install it on the thread pool threads, but in addition to being Very Dangerous, it would not achieve your actual goal (parallelization), since the `AspNetSynchronizationContext` only allows one thread in at a time. The first portion of the 3rd-party code would be able to run in parallel, but anything queued to the `AspNetSynchronizationContext` would run one thread at a time.

So, the only way I can think of making this work is to use your own custom `SynchronizationContext` that resumes on the same thread, and set `HttpContext.Current` on that thread. I have an [`AsyncContext` class](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/) that can be used for this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoIt(IEnumerable<int> inputs)
{
  var context = HttpContext.Current;
  var tasks = inputs.Select(i =>
      Task.Run(() =>
          AsyncContext.Run(() =>
          {
            HttpContext.Current = context;
            var results = Some3rdPartyTool.CallEndpointSynchronously(MyRestEndpointConfig[i]);
            return results;
          })));
  var outcome = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

So for each input, a thread is grabbed from the thread pool (`Task.Run`), a custom single-threaded synchronization context is installed (`AsyncContext.Run`), `HttpContext.Current` is set, and then the code in question is run. This may or may not work; it depends on how exactly `Some3rdPartyTool` uses its `SynchronizationContext` and `HttpContext`.

Note that there are several bad practices in this solution:

- Using `Task.Run` on ASP.NET.
- Accessing the same `HttpContext` instance simultaneously from multiple threads.
- Using `AsyncContext.Run` on ASP.NET.
- Blocking on asynchronous code (done by `AsyncContext.Run` and also presumably `Some3rdPartyTool`.

In conclusion, I again recommend updating/rewriting/replacing `Some3rdPartyTool`. But this pile of hacks *might* work.

Comment: Great answer, thanks for making it perfectly clear! As for the `Some3rdPartyTool`, as far as I found it's using webClient underneath to call the endpoints, so it's synchronous by nature (no blocking code) - my original assumption that it had some async inside was wrong

Comment: @veljkoz: If it's not doing sync-over-async, then you might be able to capture `SynchronizationContext.Current` and `HttpContext.Current` and use those to temporarily set them on other threads threads (`SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext` / `HttpContext.Current`), and that may work without using a *different* `SynchronizationContext`.